# Data Binding Fails after app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell') for Durandal

Tags: javascript, mvvm, data-binding, knockout.js, durandal

On Durandal, I have a login page that's styled different from my other pages, so taking the advice I saw on some of the posts here, I've set up *main.js* to do a:

`app.setRoot('viewmodels/login');`

And on the login page, I provide the below method in *login.js* that resets the root:

```
loginRedirect: function() {
 app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell');
 }
```

The idea is that the user should go to the login page by default, and once logged in, I will invoke the method loginRedirect, which sets *shell.html* to be the root and thus reloads the content, and he should be able to navigate other pages from there.

Here's my *login.html*:

```
<div class="login">
  <div data-bind="compose:'header-nav-plain.html'"></div>
  <div class="container">
  <!-- Content here-->
  </div>
</div>

<div data-bind="compose:'viewmodels/footer'"></div> 
<a class="go-inner-pages" data-bind="click: loginRedirect" href="#">Test link to go to 'inner' pages</a>
```

And here's my *shell.html*, that is the doorway to all other pages:

```
<div>
  <div data-bind="compose:'viewmodels/header-nav'"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div data-bind="compose:'viewmodels/site-nav'"></div>
    <div data-bind="router"></div>
  </div>
  <div data-bind="compose:'viewmodels/footer'"></div>
</div>
```

You can see that shell.html is slightly different in structure from login.html, in that it binds to a different *header-nav.html*, and also a *site-nav.html*. (They share the same footer.html.) So on the login page, when I click on the test link that calls the loginRedirect method, it sets the root of the app to be shell.html, which will load the default page based on the parameters passed to router.map, as defined in shell.js:

```
 activate: function(){
     //Initializing router
     router.map([
         { route: '', moduleId: 'viewmodels/dashboard', title: 'Dashboard', nav: true }     
     ])
     .buildNavigationModel();

     //More code

     return router.activate();
```

But, when I click on the test link and invoke loginRedirect, the new dashboard content is loaded, but the new header-nav and site-nav data binding didn't happen. I checked the inspector, and see that the structure has indeed changed to that of shell.html (as opposed to login.html), only data binding for header-nav and site-nav didn't happen. I.e. here's the new html after invoking loginRedirect:

```
<div>
  <div data-bind="compose:'viewmodels/header-nav'"></div><!--header nav content not bound-->
  <div class="container">
    <div data-bind="compose:'viewmodels/site-nav'"></div><!--site nav content not bound-->
    <div data-bind="router"><div class="durandal-wrapper" data-view="views/dashboard" data-active-view="true">

    <!-- Dashboard content successfully loaded -->

    </div><!--end data-bind="router"-->
  </div><!--end .container-->
  <div data-bind="compose:'viewmodels/footer'">
 <!--footer content loaded-->
 </div>
```

And from the Console (see below), one can see that while the shell and dashboard are bound, (even footer is bound a second time), header-nav and site-nav are not.

[image: Screenshot of web inspector]

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and what I might be doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your attention, hope to hear from someone soon. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

For view-only bindings, you would bind this way (we do the same as you, so I'm copying and pasting *our* code):

```
compose: {view: 'shellLeftFooter.html'}"
```

For views bound to viewModels, you bind this way:

```
compose: {model: 'viewmodels/navigation/shellNavigation'}
```

The default `viewLocator` will use the following convention:

- If a **view** is specified with **no model**, then the view must be identified with the .html extension, as I have done in the former example, and it will *not* be bound to a viewModel;
- If a **model** is specified with **no view**, as I have done in the latter example, then the model file is assumed to have a .js extension, and it is also assumed that a view exists in a folder named *views* under the *app* directory, with the same name as the model, but with an .html extension.

These aren't the only two conventions, but they are the ones germane to this discussion.  To put the above in different words, make sure you have both a *viewmodels* and a *views* directory that are siblings of each other under the *app* directory.  Make sure you give the viewModel and the view identical names, differing only in their extensions (.js for the former and .html for the latter).

I'm seeing all of your .html and .js files in the code you posted, so I'm sure what your intention is in each case (view only or model-view-viewModel).  Also, your compose binding is not quite to standard.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response. I do understand what you're talking about with regards to the convention - e.g. I have a login.js that pairs with a login.html. In fact when I loaded the dashboard page on itself, before I tried out this setRoot thing, the data binding worked just fine.

Comment: @Uebyn I wonder if the general approach is sound.  If you're offering your application under a SaaS model, or simply offering it up to your users internally at your place of work, it would seem to me that login should be part of a web *site*, not the web *app*.  That's what we do.  That way, the app isn't responsible for authentication.